# AngularJS Select2 value can not assign at first row of grid

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm using select2 tool in my project using angularjs.
While assigning value to this select2 in a grid using angularjs in first row,
it is not assigning, but if I'm trying to assign in next to first row that is from 2nd row to next, it is working fine.
Why it is happening.?
Any suggestions regarding this is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

```
<td ng-if="configRow.validation.valueType == 'Single Choice'" style="width:26%">
<!-- <input style="width:100%" type="text" ng-model="configRow.Value"  ui-select2="selectChoices" ng-blur="addToConfig()"> -->
<div class="print-blank" >
<select ui-select2 ng-model="configRow.Value"  data-placeholder="Select One" ng-change="updatedDate($index)">
<option value=""></option>
<option ng-repeat="element in configRow.validation.list track by $index" value="{{element}}" >{{element}}</option>
</select>
</div>              
</td>
```

Comment: you might share some of your actual code...

Comment: Yeah Sure. Will add some code.